# Refreshing item in DataProvider for Grid, and implementing `getId` method, in Vaadin 8

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

The [`DataProvider::refreshItem`](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.5.2/com/vaadin/data/provider/DataProvider.html#refreshItem-T-) method used by `Grid` and other widgets advises two alternate ways for the widget to identify which of the contained items you are trying to refresh:

- Rely on my beans’ implementations of `equals` and `hashCode`, identifying the same object reliably without depending on a mutable member field (property).
- Implement `getId`

To quote the JavaDoc:

> `void refreshItem(T item)`
>
> Refreshes the given item. This method should be used to inform all DataProviderListeners that an item has been updated or replaced with a new instance.
>
> For this to work properly, the item must either implement `Object.equals(Object)` and `Object.hashCode()` to consider both the old and the new item instances to be equal, or alternatively [`getId(Object)`](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.5.2/com/vaadin/data/provider/DataProvider.html#getId-T-) should be implemented to return an appropriate identifier.

That last clause above is the tricky part.

➥ My question is: **How to implement [`DataProvider::getId`](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.5.2/com/vaadin/data/provider/DataProvider.html#getId-T-)?**

Every example of a `DataProvider` I have seen results in a DataProvider being returned by other calls, or internally generated, rather than subclassing. If the normal route to a `DataProvider` does not involve subclassing while writing your own implementation, then how does one override `getId` to provide an implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still create your own data provider sub class if you want to, even though most examples use more convenient factory methods. Extending from `AbstractBackEndDataProvider` or `ListDataProvider` is usually the best starting point.

Another alternative is to use the three-arguments constructor of `CallbackDataProvider` which takes the two regular callbacks as the first two arguments and then a third callback that receives an item and should return an object that can be used as the identifier for that item.

Directly or indirectly overriding `getId` is seen as a relatively rarely used feature, so we have chosen to not pollute the top-level `DataProvider` interface with factory methods for those cases.

Comment: I do not understand why overriding `getId` would be relatively rare. It seems common enough to use a backend/repository class than returns *fresh* objects when retrieved from a database/service, to replace an old object, rather than mutate the original object. So if *replacing* objects in the data provider rather than *updating* objects, we need the `getId` method approach if not implementing `equals`/`hashCode` in such a way as to not consider mutating fields. Seems like a `getId` is simpler. I am not being argumentative, it just seems like I am missing out on something in my understanding.

Comment: The assumption is that you'd still end up implementing `equals` and `hashCode` in your data objects because you'd also need it for other purposes than `DataProvider` refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EmployeeDataProvider extends AbstractBackEndDataProvider<Employee, String> {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private final EmployeeService employeeService;

  public EmployeeDataProvider(EmployeeService employeeService) {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.employeeService = employeeService;
  }

  @Override
  protected Stream<Employee> fetchFromBackEnd(Query<Employee, String> query) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return employeeService.fetchEmployees(query.getFilter().orElse(null), query.getLimit(), query.getOffset(),
        query.getSortOrders()).stream();
  }

  @Override
  protected int sizeInBackEnd(Query<Employee, String> query) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return employeeService.countEmployees(query.getFilter().orElse(null));
  }

  @Override
  public Object getId(Employee item) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return item.getId();
  }
}
```

You can find working example code [here](https://mindbug.in/vaadin/vaadin-dataprovider-example/).